# "nmcli nm wifi on" stops hostapd

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager, hostapd, access-point

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on a computer with a built-in wifi and also a usb wifi. I want to run hostapd on built-in wifi to act as an access point though no connection will be established with it. I only need it to read signal levels from another device.

when I enter the following on terminal I am able to see the built-in wifi as an access point;

```
sudo nmcli nm wifi off
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
sudo service hostapd start
```

but since this turns off all the wireless connection, my internet connection with the usb dongle also is lost. I am able to enable it back with

```
sudo nmcli nm wifi on
```

but then the built-in wifi stops acting as an access point(not visible to other wireless devices anymore) even though iwconfig still shows the interface in master mode.

Is what i am trying to achieve impossible? 2 wireless interfaces, one in managed mode connected to internet and another one in master mode acting as an access point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the commands above, restarting the hostapd did the trick.

```
sudo service hostapd restart
```

Now the internal wifi works as an access point and the usb dongle is connected to another access point providing internet connection.